# how to install CentOS linux on cubieboard2

Tags: linux, arm

I bought a cubieboard [ A20 model ]  single board. [ [official website](http://cubieboard.org/) ]

there are some prebuild linux images like debian or ubuntu but i like to install CentOS on this board.

How to build CentOS image for this cubieboard or install CentOS from DVD or ISO file?

Comment: Belongs on http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Is CentOS mandatory or can you manage with any compatible Linux version like Linaro?

Answer (score 0):

You can not install CentOS on Cubieboard because it uses an ARM processor. CentOS works only with x86 processors. The instructions are not compatible.

Answer (score 0):

There is a distro called Red Sleeve which is a redhat/centos 3rd party arm port

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem before. You can download `CentOS-Userland-7-armv7hl-Minimal-1511-CubieTruck.img.xz` from [this link](http://buildlogs.centos.org/centos/7/isos/armhfp/CentOS-Userland-7-armv7hl-Minimal-1511-CubieTruck.img.xz).

It's for cubietruck but it works on your board. It will find your usb ports but it can't find its ethernet port. You connect to internet with usb port easily.